# Pass a unique ID with Twilio HTTP POST

Tags: sms, twilio

I am currently using Twilio to send balance notifications for customers who have opted into SMS notifications, but have run into an issue in positively identifying accounts in the message logs.  A number of customers have multiple accounts due to the nature of my industry, but naturally use the same phone number across all accounts.  Is there any way to pass a parameter containing their internal account ID in the HTTP POST request without including it in the message body?  I've searched extensively through Twilio's API docs and cannot find this addressed anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As far as I know there is currently no way to store metadata, like your account ID, within an SMS sent via Twilio.

One idea could be that you purchase a number of Twilio numbers and tie together a user's phone number, a Twilio phone number and the specific account. That way, if you always send balance notifications for a specific account from a specific number then you can identify that message in the logs as belonging to that user phone number for that account.

Alternatively, I'd have thought it would be useful for users, if they have more than one account, to see to which account you are referring in a balance notification. Would it be possible to include the account id (or some other identifier that the user would recognise) and then parse that out of the message when reconciling messages and accounts?

Comment: Thanks very much for the response.  I'll likely end up using your first suggestion as state regulations prevent us from including account numbers in SMS notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the question but if you are using twilio webhooks for status callbacks you can pass query string params through the `status_callback` parameter when making the call to send the SMS message and get it sent to your endpoint